# Azure Mobile Service API - exports.put causes Arabic text corruption

Tags: json, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a client side function that calls Azure Mobile Service (AMS) API to update a column in one of my AMS tables:

```
azureMobileClient.updateCustomerUser = function (phonenumber, UpdatedJson) {
    azureMobileClient.azureMSC.invokeApi("customer", {
        parameters: {
            phonenumber: phonenumber, jsondata: JSON.stringify(UpdatedJson)
        },
        method: "put"
    }).done(function (results) {
        console.log("updated customer json", UpdatedJson);
        console.log("updated customer result", results.result);
    }, function (error) {
        alert(error.message);
    });
}
```

And here is the exports.put code in my API on the Azure portal:

```
exports.put = function(request, response) {
console.log("customer/put");

var phonenumber = request.query.phonenumber;
var jsondata = request.query.jsondata;

console.log("customer/put phonenumber: " + phonenumber);
console.log("customer/put jsondata: " + jsondata);
console.log("customer/put request.query.jsondata: " + request.query.jsondata);

request.service.tables.getTable('User').where({ phonenumber: phonenumber, usertype: "300" }).read({
    success: function(result) {

        //Does not exist  and nothing to update; return error
        if (result.length === 0) {
            console.log("customer/put: item does not exist");
            response.send(statusCodes.NOT_FOUND, {message: "customer/put: item does not exist and not thing is updated"});
        }
        //Exists; update it
        else {

            console.log("customer/put: item exists  ");
            result[0].userjsondata = jsondata;
            request.service.tables.getTable('User').update(result[0]);
            response.send(statusCodes.OK, result[0]);
        }

    }
});
```

};

I am attempting to update a one of my AMS table column by 'putting' a stringify json ('JSON.stringify') with some injected Arabic characters.

My main problem is that Arabic characters in the stringfied json will get corrupt the minute they are returned from the API call.

Here is the console.log output that show the string before and after execution of the API function:

[image]

Comment: I suspect you are having problems because you are passing the update parameters in the query string instead of the request body. Try calling the API like this:   
   azureMobileClient.azureMSC.invokeApi("customer", {
        body: {
            phonenumber: phonenumber, jsondata: JSON.stringify(UpdatedJson)
        },
        method: "put"....
 and then in the server script reference request.body instead of request.query.

Comment: @EricHedstrom Thanks! It works. Please put your comment in an answer form and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are having problems because you are passing the update parameters in the query string instead of the request body. Try calling the API like this:

```
azureMobileClient.azureMSC.invokeApi("customer", { 
    body: { phonenumber: phonenumber,  jsondata: JSON.stringify(UpdatedJson) },
    method: "put"....
```

and then in the server script reference `request.body` instead of `request.query`.